# Supervisor wants me to withdraw from program

Tags: research-process, graduate-school, advisor

I have had continuing problems with my supervisor in that

1. I used data from a publication but didn't cite it properly (this was an honest mistake and during discussions, I plainly said that I received the data from elsewhere) leading him to accuse me of academic dishonesty.
2. I had some publications in journals not of a good standard and he started accusing me of lying and having fake publications.
3. I did a lab presentation for which I was not prepared enough and he called me lazy and incompetent.
4. I got delayed in providing him with some research material and he plainly stated that he does not want to supervise me anymore.

I am planning to talk to the chair of the dept about my issues but are these sufficient grounds for the chair to recommend that I be withdrawn from the department?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I used data from a publication but didn't cite it properly

It is hard to say from that description, but yes, that can qualify as academic dishonesty/misconduct and be grounds for removal from a program. That said, except in the most blatant and worst cases, programs, and universities, generally try and provide some other sort of punishment.

> some publications in journals not of a good standard and he started accusing me of lying

I cannot see how publishing your work would be grounds for dismissal under any circumstances. Lying obviously can be related to academic misconduct and be grounds for dismissal.

> got delayed in providing him with some research material and he plainly stated that he does not want to supervise me anymore.

Not meeting deadlines can be grounds for dismissal, but generally there is a procedure that most be followed. The fact that he does not want to supervise you anymore is probably the most problematic issue. Your program may require you to have a supervisor, if so, you will need to find a new supervisor.

It sounds like things are going poorly and a talk with the department chair (or head of graduate studies) is appropriate. If this is the first time you are talking to the department chair, then I highly doubt the conclusion of that meeting would be you being kicked out. The meeting might start the process of you being dismissed, but more likely, it will start the process of trying to improve your situation and resolve the issues.

Comment: apparently, these journals are what people term "predatory journals". However, I am of the opinion that whatever the status of a journal is, get it published if they are open for publication and accept papers.